# spatial relation between springs (points) and geological faults (polylines)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-statistics, correlation

In ArcGis 10.1 (advanced license), I have digitized the geological faults (polylines) and the location of water springs (points). Since, relying on literature, there is a potential connection between water infiltration rate and faults, I am planning to explore the relation between water springs and faults. What would be 'a' (not 'the') viable option to test for a spatial association between them?

Answer (score 2):

If your objective is to get straight line distances between your faults and your springs, I also recommend using the Linear Reference approach in addition to the Near tool.  The Locate Features Along Routes tool provides additional information that the Near tool does not provide.  It tells you the relative position along your fault where the point falls so that you can compare how far apart any pair of points are along the fault (not as the bird flies) and distinguishes whether the point was right or left of the fault with positive or negative side offset distance measurements (the NEAR_DIST value in the NEAR tool) that is easier to interpret that the NEAR_ANGLE in my opinion.

However, water generally does not flow in direct straight lines, so to analyze hydrology you would need to look into Spatial Analyst.  I am no expert on that toolset, but you can [start here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000003000000).  You would need some kind of elevation raster or Digital Elevation Model data of your area of interest to analyze the surface effects on the relationship between the springs and faults.

Comment: Thanks for your useful reply. I will look into 'Locate Features..'. I am not trying to model the groundwater flow, since I believe it is far beyond my expertise (both theoretical and practical). What I am after is to gauge if spring location is likely to be in the proximity of geological faults. I was also pondering the possibility to generate a number of random points, and use for example logistic regression to explore the correlation between presence/absence of springs and the distance from faults. But there would be also a 'vertical' factor to take into account.  Further hints are welcome.

Comment: Events for routes that have Z values can be used to calculate the Z value at the event position.  So if your original point has a Z value calculate it into a field, do Locate Features... to a fault route with Z values, then make an event table and calculate the event's Z value on the Route.  Then you can compare the elevation change relative to the distance of offset.  Line segment events can also be exported and will include the Z values of the fault for the event segment.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look through the Proximity toolset:
[Overview](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Proximity_toolset/000800000018000000/)

Specifically using Near to generate a Near Table.  Once you have this table you'd be able to graph the relationships.

Also play around with the Select by Location tools:

[with Python](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Select_Layer_By_Location/001700000072000000/) or

[with the Graphic User Interface](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_Select_By_Location/00s50000002q000000/)

Use these tools to explore what the relationship between your digitized layers.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that toolset. I have elaborated some more on what I am after in my comment to another answer, so may be you may want to read that as well. If you have further ideas (or even caveats), I will be happy to hear them.

Comment: I work for a mine, but am not a geologist.  So I have some understanding of faults, but not how they are represented.  I'm guessing that your faults are depicted on the surface.  Do you have data pertaining to there vertical orientaion or dip?  If so, once you know the distance and direction of each point (spring) from the closest line (fault) you could also project the fault lines downward and see the relationship at depth.  Or if you have a geological trend direction at each spring, than you could see where the springs and faults intersect at depth.  But these both start with a Near table.